# DropDownList1 does not exists in the current context error

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an aspx application. I have defined a dropdownlist in the .aspx file and try to load some data into it from database in .aspx.cs file. But I am getting the error in .aspx.cs as "DropDownList1" does not exists in the current context.

Below is the code:

Wiki.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Wiki.aspx.cs" Inherits="FinalProj2._Wiki" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body { margin: 4%; }
    #space1 { height:1em; }
    #space2 { height:1em; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>WIKI</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div id="space1"></div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" Height = "150px" Width = "100%"></asp:ListBox>
    <div id="space2"></div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Wiki.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using FinalProj2.Controllers;

namespace FinalProj2
{
    public partial class _Wiki : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FinalProj2.Models.DataClasses1DataContext db = new FinalProj2.Models.DataClasses1DataContext();

            Response.Write("<br/>Page.User.Identity.Name: " + Page.User.Identity.Name);
            Response.Write("<br/>Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated: " + Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            Response.Write("<br/>Page.User.Identity.AuthenticationType: " + Page.User.Identity.AuthenticationType);

            var query = from meet in db.Meets
                        select meet.Summary;
            // where meet.Meeting_ID = (from meet_emp in db.Meet_Emps
            //where meet_emp.Employee_Name == Page.User.Identity.Name
            //select meet_emp.Meeting_ID)

            DropDownList1.DataSource = query;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }//end 
    }

}
```

What could be the possible reason. According to me I feel everything is fine as had used the same way for a list box into another application.

Comment: Just curious, you have "models" and "controllers" in a Web Application Project?

Comment: I don't why it happened, but I created the application all over again and it worked not... Thanks

Comment: It's look like problem in _Wiki.designer.cs file.Open it and manually add the DropDownlist

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have no files that accidentally try to inherit or define the same (partial) Mlass as other files.

Thus no other code behind file should have same signature in **FinalProj2** Namespace.
public partial class **_Wiki** : System.Web.UI.Page